# Get sold products within date range and order them by sold quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table scheme (removed non-important columns):

[image: table scheme]

and I am programming REST API on that. I need to get paginated products sold within some date range.

This wouldn't be a problem for me, but I also need to sort them by either product's code or its sold quantity. The latter is a problem for me.

---

My idea was to query products and then use subquery to find their `sold_products` filtered by date and sum the resulting sold quantities. Then order by that sum.

This works but this really is not efficient. For every single product I have to sum it's sold products and in the end I only take 10 results (because I'm using pagination). My latest attempt using this way took 6.5 seconds, so...

---

My second idea was to go from the other side. Query sold_products, group them by `product_id`, filter them and then find it's parents.

This works well, this would be exactly it, but there is one problem - I don't get products which were not sold yet.

---

How can I do this? I think I won't need exact query, just some idea how should I approach this should be enough.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Input data in CSV (hope it's ok like this):

product:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A11 |
| 2 | A12 |
| 3 | B11 |

product_variant:

| id | product_id | code | initial_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A11-1 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | A11-2 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | A11-3 | 80 |
| 4 | 2 | A12-1 | 20 |
| 5 | 2 | A12-2 | 30 |
| 6 | 2 | A12-3 | 80 |
| 7 | 2 | A12-4 | 90 |
| 8 | 3 | B11-1 | 70 |
| 9 | 3 | B11-2 | 70 |

sold_product:

| id | product_id | product_variant | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 15 | 2021-04-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 15 | 2021-04-04 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 10 | 2021-04-05 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 19 | 2021-04-07 |
| 6 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 2021-04-07 |
| 7 | 2 | 5 | 12 | 2021-04-08 |
| 8 | 2 | 7 | 15 | 2021-04-10 |
| 9 | 2 | 7 | 15 | 2021-04-10 |

Result:

| product_id | product_code | initial_quantity | sold_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A11 | 180 | 79 |
| 2 | A12 | 220 | 53 |
| 3 | B11 | 140 | 0 or NULL |

Result when sold date range 2021-04-07 to 2021-04-08 and ordered by sold_quantity asc:

| product_id | product_code | initial_quantity | sold_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | B11 | 140 | 0 or NULL |
| 1 | A11 | 180 | 19 |
| 2 | A12 | 220 | 23 |

Sample data SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product(id INT, code VARCHAR(25));
CREATE TABLE product_variant(id INT, product_id INT, code VARCHAR(25), initial_quantity INT);
CREATE TABLE sold_product(id INT, product_id INT, product_variant_id INT, quantity INT, date_time DATETIME);

INSERT INTO product VALUES(1,'A11');
INSERT INTO product VALUES(2,'A12');
INSERT INTO product VALUES(3,'B11');

INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(1,1,'A11-1',50);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(2,1,'A11-2',50);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(3,1,'A11-3',80);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(4,2,'A12-1',20);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(5,2,'A12-2',30);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(6,2,'A12-3',80);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(7,2,'A12-4',90);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(8,3,'B11-1',70);
INSERT INTO product_variant VALUES(9,3,'B11-2',70);

INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(1,1,1,20,'2021-04-01');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(2,1,1,15,'2021-04-01');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(3,1,2,15,'2021-04-04');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(4,1,3,10,'2021-04-05');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(5,1,3,19,'2021-04-07');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(6,2,4,11,'2021-04-07');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(7,2,5,12,'2021-04-08');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(8,2,7,15,'2021-04-10');
INSERT INTO sold_product VALUES(9,2,7,15,'2021-04-10');
```

First idea:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.code,
    (
        SELECT SUM(v.initial_quantity)
        FROM product_variant AS v
        WHERE p.id = v.product_id
    ) AS initial_quantity,
    (
        SELECT SUM(s.quantity)
        FROM sold_product AS s
        WHERE p.id = s.product_id
    ) AS sold_quantity
FROM product AS p
ORDER BY sold_quantity;
```

Second idea:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.code,
    (
        SELECT SUM(v.initial_quantity)
        FROM product_variant AS v
        WHERE p.id = v.product_id
    ) AS initial_quantity,
    SUM(s.quantity) AS sold_quantity
FROM sold_product AS s
INNER JOIN product AS p ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.code, p.id,
    (
        SELECT SUM(v.initial_quantity)
        FROM product_variant AS v
        WHERE p.id = v.product_id
    )
ORDER BY sold_quantity;
```

EDIT: `JOIN` attempt, returns single result with sum of all sold quantities

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.code,
    (
        SELECT SUM(v.initial_quantity)
        FROM product_variant AS v
        WHERE p.id = v.product_id
    ) AS initial_quantity,
    SUM(s.quantity) AS sold_quantity
FROM product AS p
JOIN sold_product AS s ON p.id = s.product_id
ORDER BY sold_quantity;
```

Comment: Actually I was going to suggest something similar to you first idea there. I read that you're having issue with that one.. two issues, correct? One is _"in the end I only take 10 results (because I'm using pagination)"_  and the other is about performance. I don't really understand about the first issue and I guess for the second issue, to improve performance, you can try shifting that sub-query in `SELECT` to become `JOIN` instead and compare the performance.. and of course with correct indexes, it will run much quicker

Comment: How many different product_ids are there?

Comment: I've just tried it on production DB and the query I wrote took 18.5 seconds. When I removed that `sold_quantity` subquery, it took only 0.08 seconds.

Comment: There is nearly 4 000 rows in `product`, but in production I also have like "global filter" (`WHERE product.catalog = 1`) and this narrows it to 600 records. In `sold_product` is nearly 20 000 rows, but not all of those are linked to my 600 product records.

Comment: I forgot to answer: the "I only take a 10 results" was not meant to be an issue, I was just saying that I need to do those expensive calculations on all rows just to get 10 of them. But I still need to do some so I can sort by sold. And I also tried to replace subquery with JOIN, but it isn't working for me. It returns single result sum of all sold quantities. Maybe I did it wrong, updated question with my attempt.

Comment: Even if you only take 10 row, it still calculate all row because it used in `order by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - missing index key on `sold_product.product_id`. I never thought missing index key could slow queries **that much**, up to 30 seconds. With that index key it takes 0.1s.

Thank you all who tried to help!